# Online no-download text editor to test Chrome extension?

Tags: web-apps, software-development, chrome

I am creating a Chrome extension. I am already familiar with JSFiddle, but this does not test Chrome extensions.

Is there a JSFiddle-like text editor (no download) which will let me build and test Chrome extensions?

Please do not suggest Notepad ++ or TextWrangler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would test on my own server, in order to have full control.

If you run Linux, then you already have [Apache](http://apache.org/). If you run Windows, get a free [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WampServer), such as [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) (which I have used for many years and can highly recommend), which will run Apache on Windows.

Then you can serve test pages from [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) and debug your Chrome extension using those.

---

[Update] Since you use a Chromebook, check out:

- > A [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en), serves web pages from a local folder over the network, using HTTP. Runs offline.

(this might be the easiest option)

- [LAMP Stack on an ARM ChromeBook](http://solvitor.com/2013/01/02/lamp-stack-on-an-arm-chromebook/)
- [Installing LAMP Apache/MySQL/PHP on Chromebook/Chromebox](http://webonaut.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/installing-lamp-apachemysqlphp-on.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I am on a Chromebook. I'll edit to include this detail.

Comment: Given that ChromeOS is Linux based, you might well have, or be able to install, a local Apache server. Testing on `localhost`  is probably the best way to go about it.

Comment: See updated answer :-)

Comment: Thank you!!! I would upvote, but I am without reputation.

Comment: Don't worry. It's not about the points :-) Welcome aboard. I hope that you will be active here.